# GPPSignIn birthday attribute missing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-api, google-plus

I want to get the users birthdate with this code:

```
    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
    [plusService setAuthorizer:authObj];
    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                } else {
                    NSString *birthDay = [person birthday];
                }
            }];
```

This is the scope:

```
googleSignIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
```

I got all the informations, but the birthDay is nil.
If I check the object in runtime it doesn't have a ""birthday" key-value pair.

Anyone has any idea how to solve it?

thanks

Comment: If birthday is not there in the query/service then I you can't extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Person resource`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource) (which powers those queries) only includes a birthday field if it has been shared publicly in the user's profile settings. This is true for all of the fields in the `Person resource`. The only guaranteed values are `name`, `profile image`, `profile link`, and `age range`, which may work for your purposes.